# Build Toggle Button with Flutter Bloc

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-bloc

I am trying to build a a list from an api into a list of toggle button in this case sizes. Below is what i have tried.

```
//ToggleSizeState
enum ToggleSizeStatus { initial, success, error, loading, selected }

extension ToggleSizeStatusX on ToggleSizeStatus {
  bool get isInitial => this == ToggleSizeStatus.initial;
  bool get isSuccess => this == ToggleSizeStatus.success;
  bool get isError => this == ToggleSizeStatus.error;
  bool get isLoading => this == ToggleSizeStatus.loading;
  bool get isSelected => this == ToggleSizeStatus.selected;
}

class ToggleSizeState extends Equatable {
  const ToggleSizeState({
    this.status = ToggleSizeStatus.initial,
    List<bool>? sizeSelection,
    int idSelected = 0,
  })  : sizeSelection = sizeSelection ?? const [],
        idSelected = idSelected;

  final List<bool> sizeSelection;
  final ToggleSizeStatus status;
  final int idSelected;
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [status, sizeSelection, idSelected];

  ToggleSizeState copyWith({
    List<bool>? sizeSelection,
    ToggleSizeStatus? status,
    int? idSelected,
  }) {
    return ToggleSizeState(
      sizeSelection: sizeSelection ?? this.sizeSelection,
      status: status ?? this.status,
      idSelected: idSelected ?? this.idSelected,
    );
  }
}
```

For the toggle size event, i only have one event.

```
abstract class ToggleSizeEvent extends Equatable {
  const ToggleSizeEvent();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class SelectSize extends ToggleSizeEvent {
  const SelectSize({
    required this.idSelected,
  });
  final int idSelected;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [idSelected];
}
```

For the main Bloc, i have this:

```
class ToggleSizeBloc extends Bloc<ToggleSizeEvent, ToggleSizeState> {
  final ProductModel product;
  ToggleSizeBloc({required this.product}) : super(const ToggleSizeState()) {
    on<SelectSize>(_mapSelectSizeEventToState);
  }

  void _mapSelectSizeEventToState(
      SelectSize event, Emitter<ToggleSizeState> emit) async {
    for (int index = 0; index < state.sizeSelection.length; index++) {
      if (index == index) {
        state.sizeSelection[index] = !state.sizeSelection[index];
      } else {
        state.sizeSelection[index] = false;
      }
    }

    emit(state.copyWith(
        status: ToggleSizeStatus.selected,
        idSelected: event.idSelected,
        sizeSelection: List.generate(product.size!.length, (index) => false)));
  }
}
```

Now this is how i try to build the UI:

```
class ProductSize extends StatefulWidget {
  final ProductModel product;

  const ProductSize({super.key, required this.product});

  @override
  State<ProductSize> createState() => _ProductSizeState();
}

class _ProductSizeState extends State<ProductSize> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const Text('Please select size'),
          BlocBuilder<ToggleSizeBloc, ToggleSizeState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              return ToggleButtons(
                selectedColor: Colors.white,
                color: pureBlack,
                fillColor: thistle,
                splashColor: lilac,
                highlightColor: lilac,
                textStyle: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                renderBorder: true,
                borderColor: lilac,
                borderWidth: 1.5,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                selectedBorderColor: lilac,
                isSelected: state.sizeSelection,
                onPressed: (int newIndex) {
                  context
                      .read<ToggleSizeBloc>()
                      .add(SelectSize(idSelected: widget.product.id!));
                },
                children: [
                  for (var item in widget.product.size!)
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                      child: Text(item, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                    ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

THe error i get is **Exception has occurred.
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/material/toggle_buttons.dart': Failed assertion: line 198 pos 12: 'children.length == isSelected.length': is not true.**
Please can some one help?
For the result i want, [image: This what i plan on displaying.]

Comment: can you post toggle_buttons.dart' also?

Comment: Hello Marcel. Toggle_buttons.dart is the inbuit flutter toggle button.

Comment: in the ui, can you place a print there with the list you have at this point? before the return ToggleButtons( line

Comment: I was able to get it to work. But i cant select any option. The page now displays the sizes dynamically. Will update the question now or answer it and ask a new one. Thanks @marcel

Answer (score 0):

The state was wrong entirely. I had to use an initalizer to declare the generated list.

```
part of 'toggle_size_bloc.dart';

enum ToggleSizeStatus { initial, success, error, loading, selected }

extension ToggleSizeStatusX on ToggleSizeStatus {
  bool get isInitial => this == ToggleSizeStatus.initial;
  bool get isSuccess => this == ToggleSizeStatus.success;
  bool get isError => this == ToggleSizeStatus.error;
  bool get isLoading => this == ToggleSizeStatus.loading;
  bool get isSelected => this == ToggleSizeStatus.selected;
}

class ToggleSizeState extends Equatable {
  ToggleSizeState({
    required this.product,
    this.status = ToggleSizeStatus.initial,
    List<bool>? sizeSelection,
    int idSelected = 0,
  })  : sizeSelection = List.generate(product.size!.length, (index) => false),
        idSelected = idSelected;

  final List<bool> sizeSelection;

  final ProductModel product;
  final ToggleSizeStatus status;
  final int idSelected;
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [status, sizeSelection, idSelected];

  ToggleSizeState copyWith({
    List<bool>? sizeSelection,
    ToggleSizeStatus? status,
    int? idSelected,
  }) {
    return ToggleSizeState(
      product: product,
      sizeSelection: sizeSelection ?? this.sizeSelection,
      status: status ?? this.status,
      idSelected: idSelected ?? this.idSelected,
    );
  }
}
```

Then for the bloc, i had to remove the List.generate from the sizeSelection and call the state.sizeSelection instead.

```
part 'toggle_size_event.dart';
part 'toggle_size_state.dart';

class ToggleSizeBloc extends Bloc<ToggleSizeEvent, ToggleSizeState> {
  final ProductModel product;
  ToggleSizeBloc({required this.product})
      : super(ToggleSizeState(product: product)) {
    on<SelectSize>(_mapSelectSizeEventToState);
  }

  int newIndex = 0;

  void _mapSelectSizeEventToState(
      SelectSize event, Emitter<ToggleSizeState> emit) async {
    for (int index = 0; index < state.sizeSelection.length; index++) {
      if (index == newIndex) {
        state.sizeSelection[index] = !state.sizeSelection[index];
      } else {
        state.sizeSelection[index] = false;
      }
    }

    emit(state.copyWith(
        status: ToggleSizeStatus.selected,
        idSelected: event.idSelected,
        sizeSelection: state.sizeSelection));
  }
}
```

Now for the UI Part,

```
class ProductSize extends StatefulWidget {
  final ProductModel product;

  const ProductSize({super.key, required this.product});

  @override
  State<ProductSize> createState() => _ProductSizeState();
}

class _ProductSizeState extends State<ProductSize> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const Text('Please select size'),
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => ToggleSizeBloc(product: widget.product),
            child: BlocBuilder<ToggleSizeBloc, ToggleSizeState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                debugPrint('ToggleSize Page ${state.sizeSelection}');
                return ToggleButtons(
                  selectedColor: Colors.white,
                  color: pureBlack,
                  fillColor: thistle,
                  splashColor: lilac,
                  highlightColor: lilac,
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  renderBorder: true,
                  borderColor: lilac,
                  borderWidth: 1.5,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  selectedBorderColor: lilac,
                  isSelected: state.sizeSelection,
                  onPressed: (int newIndex) {
                    context.read<ToggleSizeBloc>().add(SelectSize(
                          idSelected: widget.product.id!,
                        ));
                  },
                  children: [
                    for (var item in widget.product.size!)
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                        child: Text(item, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                      ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The onPressed function is still not working. So i still need help with that. Hope someone can help me with that.